# Upload data from internal memory to Dropbox

Tags: internal-storage, auto-upload

I have been trying to upload xml data from the internal memory of my android phone to Dropbox. However, it only works when I use a virtual device. I currently believe that it is because the phone isn't rooted (i.e. I can access /data/data/appname/files in the file explorer for the virtual device but not the android phone) which is required to access the app's allocated internal memory. Is there a way to do this without rooting the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem. I found out that since I am restricted in accessing the app's personal storage I couldn't create the folder called "files" (from /data/data/appname/**files**), however, by directly writing the data to /data/data/appname/, I was able to access and upload the data.

Hope this helps someone.